# No sound on Skype in 18.04. Perfect before update

Tags: sound, skype

No sound after updating to Ubuntu18.04. Skype was good before.

Comment: Does 18.04 play sound, like on YouTube or something?

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me today. After trying the solutions shown nothing was solved.

Install *pavucontrol*

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

After you run the audio test with **Skype  Tools > Config Audio and Video** (in the section Speakers).

Open "**pavucontrol**" and you will be able to see that Skype is trying to use a different audio output (in my case was HDMI) I changed that and Skype audio worked again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me.  One confusing issue was that Skype's speaker test and other miscellaneous sounds were going to the correct output, but the actual audio of the call was going to a separate, incorrect output.

Comment: I had sound, but no VoIP. My problem was that I had a Bluethooth headset that was connected via cable to my PC. Skype kept using the Bluetooth audio channel, so I simply had to switch it off.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Skype and re-installing it not from Ubuntu Software. Go directly to Skype official website https://www.skype.com/es/get-skype/ and downlod the .deb file. Once you have this file on your computer, open it with the "Software installation" option, by right-clicking on the icon. Install Skype from there. Once your installation is completed, go to the terminal and type:

```
skypeforlinux
```

Then you'll be able to use Skype normally.

This installation does not create an icon for you. So you have to create it.

Comment: And once this is done, do not upgrade to the new version, contrary to what Skype might tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, probabaly because Skype is trying to use ALSA and ubuntu is using pulseaudio.

To clarify, there is sound (firefox, youtube, spotify, etc.). It only affects Skype.

You can try to resolve it, but I cannot guarantee anything.

One way is forcing ALSA to reload:

`sudo alsa force-reload`

or just reinstall everything:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload`

But **I did not do any of those** (I just hypothesize that these might help), **I went for a Skype Web interface**. It works perfectly in Google Chrome, so I suggest you give that a try. Unfortunately, it only works in Google Chrome, and no other web browser...

Comment: I've tried both but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Ubuntu's sound configurations.

1. Run skype first.
2. On Linux desktop Access settings >> sound >> tab "Application".
3. Check if the 2 sound options are enabled.
   NOTE: My case only one option was ON so the output worked and input was mute.
4. After enabling both options to go to Skype.
   [Good configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWFP7.png)
5. Access Settings >> Audio & Video >> "Make a Free test call"

Software Versions:
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Skype 8.50.0.38